# Propel won't start

Tags: propel

I installed propel and want to test the example from http://propelorm.org/documentation/02-buildtime.html . But when I want to generate the SQL-Code there is nothing happens.
I tried it as described with: propel.bat sql:build –verbose

- But when I use CMD located at my test-folder (where the propel.ini, .json, .xml, .yaml and schema.xml located) nothing happens even no error.
  If I delete the propel.php file in my test-folder than I got this error:

   **[Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]**
  **The child node "database" at path "propel" must be configured.**
- If I’m located at any other place I got this error:
    **[Propel\Common\Config\Exception\InvalidArgumentException]

  Propel expects only one configuration file**

I have set the PATH to PHP and to \vendor\bin from propel.
I suppose that the problem is something between the file \vendor\propel\propel.php and the file propel.php in my testfolder.
I used the following files:

- List item

*Propel.php* (I’m not sure with the propel.php because on the page mentioned at the beginning it starts with “” is missing). I tried both.

```
<?php
    return [
        'propel' => [
            'database' => [
                'connections' => [
                    'bookstore' => [
                        'adapter'   => 'mysql',
                        'classname'  => 'Propel\Runtime\Connection\ConnectionWrapper',
                        'dsn'       => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_db_name',
                        'user'     => 'propel',
                        'password'   => 'propel',
                        'attributes' => []
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'runtime' => [
                'defaultConnection' => 'bookstore',
                'connections' => ['bookstore']
            ],
            'generator' => [
                'defaultConnection' => 'bookstore',
                'connections' => ['bookstore']
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

*Propel.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<config>
    <propel>
        <database>
            <connections>
                <connection id="bookstore">
                    <adapter>mysql</adapter>
                    <classname>Propel\Runtime\Connection\ConnectionWrapper</classname>
                    <dsn>mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_db_name</dsn>
                    <user>propel</user>
                    <password>propel</password>
                    <attributes></attributes>
                </connection>
            </connections>
        </database>
        <runtime>
            <defaultConnection>bookstore</defaultConnection>
            <connection>bookstore</connection>
        </runtime>
        <generator>
            <defaultConnection>bookstore</defaultConnection>
            <connection>bookstore</connection>
        </generator>
    </propel>
</config>
```

*Propel.yaml*

```
propel:
    database:
        connections:
            bookstore:
                adapter: mysql
                classname: Propel\Runtime\Connection\ConnectionWrapper
                dsn: "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_db_name"
                user: propel
                password: propel
                attributes:
    runtime:
        defaultConnection: bookstore
        connections:
            - bookstore
    generator:
        defaultConnection: bookstore
        connections:
            - bookstore
```

*Propel.json*

```
{
    "propel": {
        "database": {
            "connections": {
                "bookstore": {
                    "adapter": "mysql",
                    "classname": "Propel\Runtime\Connection\ConnectionWrapper",
                    "dsn": "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_db_name",
                    "user": "propel",
                    "password": "propel",
                    "attributes": []
                }
            }
        },
        "runtime": {
            "defaultConnection": "bookstore",
            "connections": ["bookstore"]
        },
        "generator": {
            "defaultConnection": "bookstore",
            "connections": ["bookstore"]
        }
    }
}
```

*Propel.ini*

```
[propel]
;
; Database section
;
database.connections.bookstore.adapter    = mysql
database.connections.bookstore.classname  = Propel\Runtime\Connection\ConnectionWrapper
database.connections.bookstore.dsn        = mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_db_name
database.connections.bookstore.user       = propel
database.connections.bookstore.password   = propel
database.connections.bookstore.attributes =

;
; Runtime section
;
runtime.defaultConnection = bookstore
runtime.connections[0]    = bookstore

;
; Generator section
;
generator.defaultConnection = bookstore
generator.connections[0] = bookstore
```

*schema.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<database name="bookstore" defaultIdMethod="native">
    <table name="book" phpName="Book">
        <column name="id" type="integer" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true"/>
        <column name="title" type="varchar" size="255" required="true" />
        <column name="isbn" type="varchar" size="24" required="true" phpName="ISBN"/>
        <column name="publisher_id" type="integer" required="true"/>
        <column name="author_id" type="integer" required="true"/>
        <foreign-key foreignTable="publisher" phpName="Publisher" refPhpName="Book">
            <reference local="publisher_id" foreign="id"/>
        </foreign-key>
        <foreign-key foreignTable="author">
            <reference local="author_id" foreign="id"/>
        </foreign-key>
    </table>

    <table name="author" phpName="Author">
        <column name="id" type="integer" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true"/>
        <column name="first_name" type="varchar" size="128" required="true"/>
        <column name="last_name" type="varchar" size="128" required="true"/>
    </table>

    <table name="publisher" phpName="Publisher">
        <column name="id" type="integer" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" />
        <column name="name" type="varchar" size="128" required="true" />
    </table>
</database>
```

These files were autogenerated from propel in vendor/bin
*Propel.bat*

```
@ECHO OFF
SET BIN_TARGET=%~dp0/../propel/propel/bin/propel
php "%BIN_TARGET%" %*
```

*propel*

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
SRC_DIR="`pwd`"
cd "`dirname "$0"`"
cd "../propel/propel/bin"
BIN_TARGET="`pwd`/propel"
cd "$SRC_DIR"
"$BIN_TARGET" "$@"
```

and these in vendor/bin/propel/propel/bin
*propel*

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
include('propel.php');
```

*propel.bat*

```
@echo off

if "%PHPBIN%" == "" set PHPBIN=php
if not exist "%PHPBIN%" if "%PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN%" neq "" goto USE_PEAR_PATH
GOTO RUN
:USE_PEAR_PATH
set PHPBIN=%PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN%
:RUN
"%PHPBIN%" "bin\propel" %*
```

*Propel.php*

```
<?php

if (!class_exists('\Symfony\Component\Console\Application')) {
    if (file_exists($file = __DIR__.'/../../../autoload.php') || file_exists($file = __DIR__.'/../autoload.php')) {
        require_once $file;
    } elseif (file_exists($file = __DIR__.'/../autoload.php.dist')) {
        require_once $file;
    }
}

use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder;

use Propel\Runtime\Propel;

$finder = new Finder();
$finder->files()->name('*.php')->in(__DIR__.'/../src/Propel/Generator/Command')->depth(0);

$app = new Application('Propel', Propel::VERSION);

foreach ($finder as $file) {
    $ns = '\\Propel\\Generator\\Command';
    $r  = new \ReflectionClass($ns.'\\'.$file->getBasename('.php'));
    if ($r->isSubclassOf('Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command') && !$r->isAbstract()) {
        $app->add($r->newInstance());
    }
}

$app->run();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution of the problem. I had in my work-folder too much files: I had propel.xml, .yaml, .php, .json, .ini and the scheme.xml . When I decide just to take the propel.xml and the scheme.xml everything seems to function.